# Add Authorize Attribute to a controller through code

Tags: authentication, openid-connect, .net-6.0, startup, episerver

My question is related to another question I have [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73857151/addmicrosoftidentitywebapp-with-two-providers-isnt-setting-isauthenticated). Using the `[Authorize]` attribute on a controller, or, more specifically, using the `[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "MyScheme")]`, I am able to force authentication before access to a given controller is allowed.

However, we are using `EPiServer`, specifically, `EPiServer.CMS 12.7.0` and `EPiServer.Commerce 14.4.0` (along with various other `EPiServer` components). OOTB, the admin section of `EPiServer` is hidden behind the route `/episerver`. I can't add the `[Authorize]` attribute with my desired scheme to that, and so I'm hoping maybe there is a way I can do it directly within `Startup.cs`.

Currently, I'm attempting to get around that with `endpoints.MapGet("/Util/Login", async ctx => await ctx.ChallengeAsync("AADB2B.OpenIdConnect", new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "/EPiServer" }));`. The logic here is essentially, if I try to access any of the protected areas of the code (EG `/EPiServer/CMS`), I am automatically redirected to `/Util/Login`, at which point I map that to a challenge, and then redirect the user back. I can confirm the authentication works correctly - the challenge directs the user to the appropriate login page, and then the callback sends them back where I want them to go.

However, when they return, they hit the same chain, because when they go to `/EPiServer`, it thinks they aren't authenticated, and directs them back to `/Util/Login`. My theory is that I could solve this by explicitly telling it to use my specific authentication scheme, but I can't figure out how to do that.

I've also tried:

`endpoints.MapGet("/Util/Login", async ctx => ctx.Response.Redirect("/PathThatLeadsToAChallenge"))`

`endpoints.MapGet("/Util/Login", async ctx => ctx.Response.Redirect("/")).RequireAuthorization(authorizeData: new AuthorizeAttribute { AuthenticationSchemes = "MyScheme" })`

Neither worked. Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to implement SSO? If you so might find this helpful: https://docs.developers.optimizely.com/content-cloud/v12.0.0-content-cloud/docs/integrate-azure-ad-using-openid-connect

Comment: Hey Ted - sadly, that doc doesn't address the issue I'm facing, as it is written using `AddOpenIdConnect` and not `AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution ended up being to stop using `AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp`, and return to using `AddOpenIdConnect` (as Ted suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73871299/add-authorize-attribute-to-a-controller-through-code?noredirect=1#comment130459256_73871299)). Why this ended up working is a mystery to me, but for now, I have other priorities to address.